# Google Script getRange(function returned A1Notation)

Tags: google-apps-script

I cant seem to get a A1Notation value to work in my getRange()

Below is the the function I am calling

```
function SelectedCell() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveRange().getA1Notation();
}
```

Below is the function I am calling from

```
function getComments() {
  var ss =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetComments = ss.getSheetByName("Comments");
  var cell = sheetComments.getRange("A1");
  var firstFreeRow = sheetComments.getRange(SelectedCell);
}
```

Comment: Functions need to be invoked, even if they don't expect to receive any parameters.

Comment: Thank you,  I understand now that invoke with () will return the output instead of the entire function.  This will be very useful

Answer (score 1):

As [tehhowch noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51471147/google-script-getrangefunction-returned-a1notation#comment89910717_51471147), you are passing the function variable, `SelectedCell`, not its output, as an argument to `getRange`. To execute or call a function variable, you must invoke it with `()` after:

```
function bar() { return 1; };
function foo() {
  Logger.log(bar)  // "function bar() { return 1; };"
  Logger.log(bar()) // 1, because we called the function
}
```

Try passing in the output of `SelectedCell`, which is the desired string in A1 notation, instead:

```
function getComments() {
  // ...
  var firstFreeRow = sheetComments.getRange(SelectedCell());
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I had been confused about this. () is the answer I was looking for